# Python Google Sheet API: googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: sheets version: v4

Tags: python, pyinstaller, google-sheets-api

I wrote some .py file to access and write data on my google sheet, and used pyinstaller to pack those files to .exe. However after I pack .py into .exe, I can't execute it anymore

It keeps showing this error:

```
 File "GoogleSheet.py", line 9, in __init__
  File "Google_Process.py", line 31, in __init__
  File "googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
  File "googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 287, in build
  File "googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 404, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: sheets  version: v4
```

I have tried the method: https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/issues/490

but I'm not sure how to modify my code, or if this method can fix my error.

This is my .py:

```
from Google_Process import GoogleAPIClient
import pandas as pd

class GoogleSheets(GoogleAPIClient):
    def __init__(self, status = 'DONE', order_number = '') -> None:
        self.status = status
        self.order_number = order_number
        # Call GoogleAPIClient.__init__()，give serviceName, version, scope
        super().__init__(
            'sheets',
            'v4',
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
        )

    def appendWorksheet(self):
        if self.status == 'DONE':
            df=pd.DataFrame(
            {'Order': [self.order_number],
            'Status': ['DONE'],
            'Mark': ['-']}
            )
            self.googleAPIService.spreadsheets().values().append(
                spreadsheetId='<ID>',
                range='sheet1',
                valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
                body={
                    'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
                    'values': df.values.tolist()
                },
            ).execute()
            return
```

And this is another file:

```
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

class GoogleAPIClient:
    SECRET_PATH = '.\\PackingElf\\.credentials\\client_secrets_file.json'
    CREDS_PATH = '.\\PackingElf\\.credentials\\cred.json'
    
    def __init__(self, serviceName: str, version: str, scopes: list) -> None:
        self.creds = None
        # The file client_secret.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.

        if os.path.exists(self.CREDS_PATH):
            self.creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(self.CREDS_PATH, scopes)

        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not self.creds or not self.creds.valid:
            if self.creds and self.creds.expired and self.creds.refresh_token:
                self.creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    self.SECRET_PATH, scopes)
                self.creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open(self.CREDS_PATH, 'w') as token:
                token.write(self.creds.to_json())
            
            self.googleAPIService = build(serviceName, version, credentials=self.creds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    googleSheetAPI = GoogleAPIClient(
        'sheets',
        'v4',
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
        )

    print(googleSheetAPI.googleAPIService)
```

Is there any way to fix this? Please

and i use vscode as IDE

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue when creating an inventory application that reads and writes to a google spreadsheet. I've tried roughly 4 different solutions that I've seen online, with no luck. I'm going to redirect you to this thread [thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/876) on github. Seems like it's an on-going issue.